# where to write dom manipulation code when using knockout and MVVM part 2

Tags: knockout.js

Hi guys i asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928558/where-to-write-dom-manipulation-code-when-using-knockout-and-mvvm) yesterday about where to code dom manipulation / animations etc when using knockout.  I had previously coded this into the viewmodel and was advised this is not correct.

Ive now updated my code and created custom binding handlers as advised, however i need to call a method of my viewmodel from within the custom binding handler.  Specifically when the animation completes.  Ive done it like this

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideUp = {
    init:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context){
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var parent = allBindings.parent;

        $(element).click(function(){
            if(parent.SelectedEmployee() === valueAccessor())return;

            var $PanelWrapper = $('#' + allBindings.panelName); 
            var $Bottom = parseInt($PanelWrapper.css("bottom"));

            if($Bottom === 0){
                $PanelWrapper.animate({
                    bottom:"-95"
                }, 500, function(){
                    parent.Select(valueAccessor());
                }).animate({
                    bottom:"0"
                }, 500);
            }else{
                parent.Select(valueAccessor());

                $PanelWrapper.animate({
                    bottom:"0px"
                }, 500);       
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my binding is

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Emps">
            <tr data-bind="slideUp: $data, parent: $parent, panelName: 'PanelWrapper'">
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

As you can see im passing in a reference to the viewmodel and also the id of the tag i want to animate.  Im just wondering if this is the correct way to do this.  Is there a better way to reference the viewmodel, am i calling the method of the viewmodel correctly and is it ok to pass in the id of the html tag i want to use.  It all works fine, but im keen to improve

heres a link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricobano/DCP8T/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now applying the binding to the element containing the employee. I think it would be better to apply the `SelectedEmployee` observable  to the `#PanelWrapper` so you can show/hide it depending on the value of `SelectedEmployee`:

```
<div id="PanelWrapper" data-bind="EmployeePanel: $root.SelectedEmployee"></div>
```

Then your JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel = {
    currentEmployee: null,
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        this.setEmployee(element, ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        this.setEmployee(element, ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },
    setEmployee: function(element, value) {
        if (value === currentEmployee) return; // already selected employee
        this.currentEmployee = value;
        if (value) {
            $(element).fadeIn(); // show and populate the panel here
        } else {
            $(element).fadeOut(); // hide the panel here
        }
    }
};
```

So now your employee row will look like this:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $root.OnEmployeeClick">
```

And your `ViewModel`:

```
self.OnEmployeeClick = function(employee) { self.SelectedEmployee(employee); };
```

Comment: BTW you can update @Richard fiddle example and post it with your code.

Comment: I know, but he's just trying to find out whether his approach is good / can be improved. My code is untested and has to be completed for his case, but I'm sure he'll have no problems implementing it.