# where to write dom manipulation code when using knockout and MVVM part 3

Tags: knockout.js

ive been playing with knockout and with the help off people on here and the docs I have got some way to achieving what I need however I still have a problem and im not sure how to address it.

Basically im trying to slide up a panel when a user clicks on a list of employees.  The panel has more details that the user can edit and either save or reject.

on a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942989/where-to-write-dom-manipulation-code-when-using-knockout-and-mvvm-part-2) I was advised to create a binding on the panel to an observable in my viewmodel and then create a custom binding that gets called when the observable changes.  My code is below

```
ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel = {
    currentEmployee:null,
    SelectEmployee:function(element, value){
        if(value === ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel.currentEmployee){
            return;
        }

        ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel.currentEmployee = value;

        var $PanelWrapper = $(element); 
        var $Bottom = parseInt($PanelWrapper.css("bottom"));

        if($Bottom === 0){
            $PanelWrapper.animate({
                bottom:"-95"
            }, 500).animate({
                bottom:"0"
            }, 500);
        }else{
            $PanelWrapper.animate({
                bottom:"0px"
            }, 500);       
        }
    },

    update:function(element, valueAccessor){
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        if(value == null){
            return;
        }

        ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel.SelectEmployee(element, value);
    }
}
```

and here is my binding

```
<div id="PanelWrapper" data-bind="EmployeePanel: Editable">
        <div id="Pagination">
            Prev | Next
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: Editable" id="EmployeeDetails">
            <div >
               <label>Name</label><input data-bind="value: Name" />   
               <label>Position</label><input data-bind="value: Position" /> 
               <label>Age</label><input data-bind="value: Age" class="SmallTextField"/>
               <label>Status</label><input data-bind="value: MaritalStatus" />
               <button data-bind="click: $parent.Accept">Save</button>
               <button data-bind="click: $parent.Reject">Cancel</button>     
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now my problem is that when the page loads it automarically slides up even when the observable is null.  To combat this I put a check in, but now the panel will not slide down when the observable is nulled.  How can I handle this situation?

```
if(value == null){
            return;
        }
```

Here a link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricobano/HHDSy/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the code to hide the panel in to the update, before the value == null check and then just let the SelectEmployee method deal with showing the panel again.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel = {
    currentEmployee:null,
    SelectEmployee:function(element, value){
        if(value === ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel.currentEmployee){
            return;
        }

        ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel.currentEmployee = value;

        var $PanelWrapper = $(element); 
        var $Bottom = parseInt($PanelWrapper.css("bottom"));

        if($Bottom === 0){
            $PanelWrapper.animate({
                bottom:"0"
            }, 500);
        }else{
            $PanelWrapper.animate({
                bottom:"0px"
            }, 500);       
        }
    },

    update:function(element, valueAccessor){
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        var $PanelWrapper = $(element);
        $PanelWrapper.animate({
                bottom:"-95"
        }, 500);

        if(value == null)
            return;

        ko.bindingHandlers.EmployeePanel.SelectEmployee(element, value);
    }
}
```